# How to get closest smallest number using linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sql table like this,

```
SomeDouble      SomeInt
1.00              121
1.50              124
2.00              200
2.50              321
```

and so on... up to 10,000 for SomeDouble

Now I can have a decimal number anywhere between 0.0 to 10,000.00 and I need to find the correct row for it. For example if number is 1.12 then I want it to return 121.

1.49 should return 121, 1.50 should return 124, 1.51 should return 124.

Trimmed version of what I am trying is,

```
var myValue = 1.12
var SomeInt = (from mainTable in table1
                        join table3 in table2 on mainTable.someId equals table3.someId
                        where table3.Column1 == Column1 && mainTable.SomeDouble >= myValue
                        select mainTable.SomeInt).FirstOrDefault();
```

but my output is 124. How can I change above to get me the closest smallest number then myValue ?

Comment: Should `where ... mainTable.SomeDouble >= myValue` actually be `where ... mainTable.SomeDouble <=(FLIPPED) myValue` if you want the next `smallest` number?

Comment: Should there be a database entry with a SomeDouble value of 0.00?

Comment: @AndrewMorton smallest value is 0.50

Comment: @Mathematics Did my comment of just switching the `<=` not work? It should pull the value that's the next smallest instead of next biggest. Your code looked fine to me besides that.

Comment: @dvo it doesn't works

Comment: @Mathematics what does it return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `SomeDouble` values are integers and half-integers, you can round up `myValue` to the next multiple of 0.5:

```
var myValueToLookUp = Math.Ceiling(myValue * 2) / 2;
```

and then look up the value of `SomeInt` directly with `mainTable.SomeDouble == myValueToLookUp` to avoid any confusion or inefficiency with <= or >=.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can express the closest as:

```
select t.*
from t
order by abs(SomeDouble - 1.12)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

A more efficient method would narrow it down to two rows first:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.*
       from t
       where t <= 1.12
       order by SomeDouble desc
       fetch first 1 row only
      )  union all
      ((select t.*
       from t
       where t > 1.12
       order by SomeDouble asc
       fetch first 1 row only
      )
     ) t
order by (SomeDouble - 1.12)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq queries:

```
        var above = (from mainTable in table1
            join table3 in table2 on mainTable.someId equals table3.someId
            where table3.Column1 == Column1 && mainTable.SomeDouble >= myValue
            orderby mainTable.SomeDouble
            select new {SomeInt = mainTable.SomeInt, SomeDouble = mainTable.SomeDouble}).FirstOrDefault();

        var below = (from mainTable in table1
            join table3 in table2 on mainTable.someId equals table3.someId
            where table3.Column1 == Column1 && mainTable.SomeDouble < myValue
            orderby mainTable.SomeDouble descending 
            select new {SomeInt = mainTable.SomeInt, SomeDouble = mainTable.SomeDouble}).FirstOrDefault();

        int SomeInt;
        if (above == null)
            SomeInt = below.SomeInt;
        else if (below == null)
            SomeInt = above.SomeInt;
        else if (Math.Abs(below.SomeDouble - myValue) <= Math.Abs(above.SomeDouble - myValue))
            SomeInt = below.SomeInt;
        else 
            SomeInt = above.SomeInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the linq extension method to order the records by absolute difference of SomeDouble, then by SomeInt to get the smallest first for 2 or more matches, and then we get the first one. It looks like both columns exist on main table, so I'm guessing we can limit that first then join whatever you want to it.

```
mainTable.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.SomeDouble - myValue)).ThenBy(x => x.SomeInt).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it in SQL, then

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SomeInt), 0)
FROM DoubleToInt
WHERE SomeDouble <= 1.12
```